# I can't get $cordovaFileOpener2 to work with my ionic app.

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build an ionic app that opens a PDF on the user's device when they click a link. However, I'm getting the following error in chrome

```
ionic.bundle.js:25642 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
$cordovaFileOpener2Provider <- $cordovaFileOpener2 <- FileOpenerController http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24cordovaFileOpener2Provider%20%3C-%20%24cordovaFileOpener2%20%3C-%20FileOpenerController
    at ionic.bundle.js:13380
    at ionic.bundle.js:17574
    at Object.getService [as get] (ionic.bundle.js:17721)
    at ionic.bundle.js:17579
    at getService (ionic.bundle.js:17721)
    at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:17753)
    at extend.instance (ionic.bundle.js:22311)
    at nodeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:21421)
    at compositeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:20853)
    at compositeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:20857)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:25642(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:22421processQueue @ ionic.bundle.js:27887(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:27895Scope.$eval @ ionic.bundle.js:29158Scope.$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:28969scopePrototype.$digest @ hint.js:1364Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:29263scopePrototype.$apply @ hint.js:1427done @ ionic.bundle.js:23676completeRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:23848requestLoaded @ ionic.bundle.js:23789
```

Here's my app.js

```
angular.module('CCSD_Risk', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
      StatusBar.style(1); //Light
    }
  });
});
```

And here's my controller main.js

```
console.log('main.js loaded');

angular.module('CCSD_Risk')

.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.helloWorld = function() {
        console.log('helloWorld');
    };
})

.controller('FileOpenerController', function($scope, $cordovaFileOpener2, $ionicPlatform) {
    console.log('hi 1');
    $scope.openPDF = function() {
        console.log('hi');
        $cordovaFileOpener2.open(
            'flood-plans/cambeiro.pdf', // Any system location, you CAN'T use your appliaction assets folder
            'application/pdf'
        ).then(function() {
            console.log('Success');
        }, function(err) {
            console.log('An error occurred: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    };
})
.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
    $scope.testConsole = function() {
        console.log("this is a working controller");
    }
});
```

I've tried adding the dependency ngCordova to my app.js file but that caused even more errors to occur. I'm not sure what to do at this point. This is the first app I've tried building in ionic and I'm not too familiar with angularJS. Please let me know if you need to see any of my other files.

Comment: add ngCordova and module need for $cordovaFileOpener2Provider

Answer (score 0):

check out

[error discusstion link](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide)
 and 
solution
[pluging](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide)

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js, add ngCordova dependency:

`angular.module('CCSD_Risk', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']);`

in index.html, make sure you added this line:

`<script src="lib/ngCordova/ng-cordova.js"></script>`

right above this existing one:

`<script src="cordova.js"></script>`

of course, you need to have `ng-cordova.js` in `lib/ngCordova` forder of your app

Comment: This solved the error I was getting above. However, now whenever I click a link that is supposed to call the openPDF function I get a cordova is not defined error.

Comment: that is because functionality related to cordova plugins is available only on a real device or a simulator

Comment: @Art Vandelay i need help...i just can't make it work....i am using ionic but i don't have a file ng-cordova.js how to get it?